# Delete records after 15 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, sql-delete

I've got an inactive system. It is supposed to delete users from inactive table after 15 minutes.
I have also a code that logs the user out if it cant be found in that table.
The inactive script updates user on every page refresh.

This is the inactive code I tried and it doesn't work so far:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM inactive");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

if ($row['inactive'] > timestampadd(MINUTE, -15, now()))
  {



    }else {

$db_query = "DELETE FROM inactive WHERE username='$username'";
$result = mysql_query($db_query);


    }
```

Comment: Do you *really* want to **delete** the data, or simply know that it's no longer active?

Comment: I want to **delete** the data.

Comment: Have you considered using the MySQL [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/events.html)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `remove_inactives`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
    DELETE FROM `inactive`
        WHERE `timestamp` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
;
```

**^ Use a set and forget recurring [MySQL Event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html).**
Let the server do the work for you :)

**For PHP:**

```
mysqli_query($connection, // or mysql_query(
<<<SQL
    CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `remove_inactives`
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    ENABLE
    DO
        DELETE FROM `inactive`
            WHERE `timestamp` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
    ;
SQL;
); // ends *_query() call
```

**You just need to RUN THIS ONCE to install on the server!**

Comment: Hm.. thanks! :) But i need something that works while the page is closed by the user :S got some suggestions??

Comment: @Peter This works while the site is NOT visited! It happens ALL the time, 15 minutes in between. Why do extra work in the frontend and impact performance?

Comment: Okei thanks! But i didnt understand so much from that code. I'm alitle new to coding! Is that php? And i think i have not created an event, what do you mean by that? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Peter That code is MySQL. You need to wrap in a PHP query instruction. I apologize. I always think that everyone else know at least as much as I do and take some things for granted. I'll update the response in a moment.

Comment: Oh okei, no problem CodeAngry ;) Thanks

Comment: Didnt understand all of the FOR PHP event codes, but i'll figure it out i guess. I just dont get the event. is it something i need to create in the database or in the php file? and how do i create a event ? I'll search it up. Thanks for the help any way!

Comment: @Peter Gave you a link to the MySQL Event Documentation in the post. There's nothing to understand that's not explained there. *That's where you learn stuff from*: `specifications` and `documentations`.

Comment: I added it in the sql and it seemed to load it. dont know why it wont delete :/ hm.. but thanks

Comment: @Peter It works every 15 minutes. It WILL delete if you have permission to create events and your DB structure is right.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a timestamp field you can just do a single query and not have to iterate over the result set from your select:

```
DELETE FROM inactive
WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

You can execute that query in a cron or on your page.

Comment: It worked, thanks! But what i really need is a script or something that works while the page is closed by the user. But thanks so far!

Comment: Try cron or an event like @CodeAngry suggested.