# PHP: Delete records after 15 minutes based on values across different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, multiple-tables

I have created a page to make room reservations in a library. When ever a user comes and takes the key, the "checked-out" column of its entry is updated to "1". The user can be late for maximum 15 minutes. After 15 minutes the reservation will be deleted so other users can book the room.

The table `room_reservation` has a column named `reservation_id`. The number in this column is used in two other tables. Duration, owner of reservation and a few other information are stored in this table.

The table `reservation_checked_out` has the column `checked_out` (by default `0`) keeping the value 0 or 1. Another column is `entity_id` where the information is stored for which reservation the key has been checked-out. `Entity_id` in this table matches with `reservation_id` from the `table room_reservation`.

The table `reservation_datetime` holds in the column `reservation_datetime_value` for when the reservation has been made and the column `entity_id` for which reservation. Again: `entity_id` in this table matches with `reservation_id` from the `table room_reservation`.

How can I delete a reservation in the table `room_reservation` if the key is not checked out in table `reservation_checked_out.checked_out` but the reservation started 15 miutes ago in table `reservation_datetime.reservation_datetime_value`?

Any idea as to how I could make this work?

Comment: You will need to use cron (if using linux) or windows scheduler or some other sort of scheduler. You should have a script that is run every X minutes and that checks your database for later arrivals (or whatever you need to check) and update the table accordingly.
You can either call a php file or call a URL to accomplish this.

Comment: use cron jobs accordingly

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Delete records after 15 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631363/php-delete-records-after-15-minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this SQL query:

```
DELETE r.* FROM `room_reservation` r INNER JOIN `reservation_checked_out` c ON (c.entity_id = r.reservation_id), `reservation_datetime` d ON (d.entity_id = r.reservation_id) WHERE c.checked_out = 0 AND d.reservation_datetime_value <= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE;
```

You can execute this via PHP with a cron job.